# Comparison between pointer and int (id to int) - Object wrapping still doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, integer, nsarray, nsnumber

I can't seem to figure this out.  The first if statement comparison to 0 works fine, no warnings.  But `int`'s greater than 0 give a warning about comparing the `id` object to `int`.

```
    NSMutableArray *locks = [self.compareArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSNumber *locksData = [locks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger locked = [locksData integerValue];

    if ([self.lockArray objectAtIndex:[locksData integerValue]] == 0) {
        // code
    } else if ([self.lockArray objectAtIndex:locked] == 1) {
        // code
    } else if ([self.lockArray objectAtIndex:[locksData integerValue]] == 2) {
        // code
    }
```

I populated `compareArray` with 20 `NSNumber` objects and I did not populate anything for `lockArray` yet.  It will eventually be populated with the same type of objects.

Any reason for this warning?  I also tried `intValue` as well as trying the two forms of comparison as seen in the `if` statements.

Comment: I guess you didn't read what I posted.  I already converted the pointer to an integer in 2 separate occasions but I keep getting a warning.

Comment: Yes, I did read it. That's why I marked it a duplicate. You are not converting the object you access from `self.lockArray` before trying to compare it to 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: Ohhhh crap right that makes sense. I'm an idiot.  I was mistaking it for `compareArray`.  Sorry